# myData not defined when running the server in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let myData = new contact(req.body)
});
myData.save().then(() => {
        res.send("This item has been saved to the database")
    })
    .catch(() => {
        res.status(400).send("item was not saved to the database")
    });
```

I am getting error myData is not defined

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the scope like this

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
 let myData = new contact(req.body)
  myData.save().then(() => {
    res.send("This item has been saved to the database")
  })
  .catch(() => {
    res.status(400).send("item was not saved to the databse")
  });
});
```

In your code, myData is out of the scope so you get the undefined error.